# How to give empty value for argument in POST request for hyperledger composer rest server

Tags: r, rest, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, httr

I am trying to make a post request via R using the httr package to composer rest server. I have written a code and then created the composer rest server from it. These are my details

Request URL : http://localhost:3000/api/nl.amis.registry.fruits

`Body: {
"$class": "nl.amis.registry.fruits",
"Id": "9",
"name": "orange",
"description": "string",
"count": ""
}`

First, I have tried with the composer rest server. For my purpose, I needed the count to be blank and the value will be appended by another API call. I was able to make the transaction successfully with the **count: ""**. This I was able to check in the test section of the composer playground. The remaining code works fine which appends the count variable later on.

Now I am writing an R code to make a similar transaction through POST request. Here I am facing an error that **"count cannot be blank"** and returns with error **422 Unprocessable entity**. The content type I was used was **application/json**. While using the **"count":{}** , the post request process fine and i am getting **"count":[object Object]** in the response. But the later on code which does the appending will do something like **count:"[object Object],1"** wherein I am expecting **"count":"1"**. Everything works fine while using the test in composer playground but while trying to access externally via rest API is creating the problem. Please help.

Comment: - its a loopback validation response (ie when invoked via REST APIs as Composer REST server is a loopback app), there is an open issue for this in Composer (try using `optional` if you can) - https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4312

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony : Thank you for the reply. Let me try it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use an `Optional` keyword to declare a `count` in an asset of the model file. using `Optional` keyword you can post an empty value of `count`.

> for example:

```
  asset fruits identified by Id {
    o String Id
    o String name
    o String description
    o String count optional
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me check it out and if it's working I will accept this as the answer.